# Set custom spatial reference to base map in arcgis javascript api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system

How can I set my spatial reference to the base map in arcgis api. I want to change the default spatial reference.

Comment: how can i design a map of an country called aruba in the world map .please help me out

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/127692)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spatial reference for a map is defined either by the [extent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#extent) passed to the map constructor or by the first layer added to the map. Checkout the [any projection](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/fl_any_projection.html) sample to see how to specify different spatial references for a map.

If you're using the [basemap](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1) or center and zoom options with the map constructor, the map's spatial reference will be web mercator.